# PDF file not printed

Tags: pgfplots

I am using MikTeX to compile the following code.  Why isn't the pdf file printed?

If I remove

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
```

from the preamble of the code, a pdf file is printed.  Why does that make difference?  (I did not include the code for graphing the function.)

At the suggestion of `cfr`, a member of `tex.stackexchange`, I added `\listfiles` to the preamble.  The following was found in the `.text` file.

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.11.5)  17 NOV 2015 07:52
entering extended mode
**Compile-2.tex
(Compile-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsart.cls"
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
\linespacing=\dimen102
\normalparindent=\dimen103
\normaltopskip=\skip41
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip42

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen104
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count79
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count80
\leftroot@=\count81
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count82
\DOTSCASE@=\count83
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen106
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count84
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count85
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count86
\dspbrk@lvl=\count87
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count88
\column@=\count89
\maxfields@=\count90
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen107
\alignsep@=\dimen108
\tagshift@=\dimen109
\tagwidth@=\dimen110
\totwidth@=\dimen111
\lineht@=\dimen112
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip43
\multlinetaggap=\skip44
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 388.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert233
\abstractbox=\box28
\listisep=\skip45
\c@part=\count91
\c@section=\count92
\c@subsection=\count93
\c@subsubsection=\count94
\c@paragraph=\count95
\c@subparagraph=\count96
\c@figure=\count97
\c@table=\count98
\abovecaptionskip=\skip46
\belowcaptionskip=\skip47
\captionindent=\dimen113
\thm@style=\toks19
\thm@bodyfont=\toks20
\thm@headfont=\toks21
\thm@notefont=\toks22
\thm@headpunct=\toks23
\thm@preskip=\skip48
\thm@postskip=\skip49
\thm@headsep=\skip50
\dth@everypar=\toks24
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.te
x"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks25
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen114
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen115

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
"
\pgfutil@abb=\box29
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks26
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count99
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen116
\Gin@req@width=\dimen117
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
"
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks27
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks28

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks29
))
\pgf@x=\dimen118
\pgf@y=\dimen119
\pgf@xa=\dimen120
\pgf@ya=\dimen121
\pgf@xb=\dimen122
\pgf@yb=\dimen123
\pgf@xc=\dimen124
\pgf@yc=\dimen125
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count100
\c@pgf@countb=\count101
\c@pgf@countc=\count102
\c@pgf@countd=\count103
\t@pgf@toka=\toks30
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks31
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks32

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef"
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-p
df.def"
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count104
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count105
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex
"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen126
\pgfmath@count=\count106
\pgfmath@box=\box30
\pgfmath@toks=\toks33
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks34
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks35
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count107
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen127
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen128
\pgf@picminy=\dimen129
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen130
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen131
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen132
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen133
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen134
\pgf@xx=\dimen135
\pgf@xy=\dimen136
\pgf@yx=\dimen137
\pgf@yy=\dimen138
\pgf@zx=\dimen139
\pgf@zy=\dimen140
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen141
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen142
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen143
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen144
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box31
\pgf@hbox=\box32
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box33
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count108
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen145
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen146
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen147
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen148
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen149
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen150
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count109
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box34
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box35
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex"
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen151
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen152
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
)) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen153
\pgffor@skip=\dimen154
\pgffor@stack=\toks36
\pgffor@toks=\toks37
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.cod
e.tex"
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count110
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen155
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen156
\tikz@lasty=\dimen157
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen158
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen159
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen160
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen161
\tikz@figbox=\box36
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box37
\tikz@tempbox=\box38
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box39
\tikztreelevel=\count111
\tikznumberofchildren=\count112
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count113
\tikz@fig@count=\count114

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count115
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count116
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count117
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count118

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2013/07/15 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibraryangles.code.tex"
File: tikzlibraryangles.code.tex 2013/08/28 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex 2008/10/06 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibraryintersections.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryinterse
ctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryfpu.cod
e.tex")
\pgf@intersect@solutions=\count119
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex"
File: tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex 2014/03/21 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.4)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduledecoration
s.code.tex"
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen162
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen163
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen164
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen165
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen166
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count120
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen167
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen168
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box40
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\decorations\pgfli
brarydecorations.markings.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\decorations\pgfli
brarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex 2013/07/18 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.3)
\pgf@layerbox@background=\box41
\pgf@layerboxsaved@background=\box42
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex 2008/01/15 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibrarypattern
s.code.tex"
File: pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex 2008/03/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.13)
))
```

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,backgrounds,patterns}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}


\begin{document}


\noindent {\bf Example} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
Determine the equations of the tangent lines to
\begin{equation*}
r(x) = \frac{x - 1}{x + 1}
\end{equation*}
at the points $P = (-3, \, 2)$ and $Q = (1, \, 0)$.
\end{minipage}
\vskip0.2in

\noindent {\bf Determination of the equations of the tangent lines at \boldmath$P$ and $Q$\unboldmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks{
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(-3+h) - r(-3)}{h} \\
&\qquad = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\dfrac{(-3 + h) - 1}{(-3 + h) + 1} - 2}{h} \\
&\qquad = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\dfrac{-4 + h}{-2 + h} - 2}{h} \\
&\qquad = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-4 + h - (-4 + 2h)}{h(-2 + h)} \\
&\qquad = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-h}{h(-2 + h)} \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{2} ,
\intertext{and}
&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(1+h) - r(1)}{h} \\
&\qquad = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\dfrac{(1 + h) - 1}{(1 + h) + 1}}{h} \\
&\qquad = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h}{h(2 + h)} \\
&\qquad = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{2 + h} \\
&\qquad = \frac{1}{2} .
\end{align*}
}So, $r$ does have derivatives at 1 and $-3$, $r^{\prime}(-3) = r^{\prime}(1) = 1/2$, and the tangent lines to the graph of $r$ at $P$ and at $Q$ both have slope of $1/2$. The equation of the tangent line at $P$ is $y = (1/2)x - 1/2$, and the equation of the tangent line at $Q$ is $y = (1/2)x + 7/2$. \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\vskip0.25in

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any errors? Warnings? Anything in the log?

Comment: The code you posted compiles to PDF just fine for me. Have you tried deleting all generated files and recompiling? (e.g. `.aux` etc.) By the way, `\bf` etc. are deprecated 20+ years ago. They should not be used in LaTeX 2e. Try `\bfseries` instead.

Comment: @cfr  No errors.  I can delete the .aux and .text files now.

Comment: @cfr   Nope.  Didn't give me a pdf file.  Why would the code compile and give me a pdf file without `\usepackage{pgfplots}` and `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`?

Comment: I don't know because I can't reproduce the problem. It doesn't give me any errors at all. I don't have to comment those lines in order to get it to compile.

Comment: It would be good if somebody with MikTeX could test. I'm using TeX Live. Can you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and add the file list to your question. Maybe you have a different version and that's somehow implicated. The log file is definitely worth a look, as I suggested above.

Comment: I've just tested with MiKTeX, and have absolutely no problem.

Comment: Why did this get down voted exactly?

Comment: @cfr  I added `\listfiles` in the preamble.  This is what it said in the .text file. "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.11.5)  17 NOV 2015 07:52
entering extended mode  **Compile-2.tex (Compile-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded."

Comment: @Bernard  See my last comment to cfr.  Thanks.

Comment: @cfr  I added the output from the `.text` file to my original post.  Thanks for the suggestion to add `\listfiles` in the preamble.

Comment: @user74973: Compiling an my system, I have these more lines at the very beginning of the .log file: `Command Line: pdflatex.exe --enable-write18 --interaction=errorstopmode --include-directory="E:\Tests\TikZ" --synctex=1 "pbprintingpdf.tex"`. By the way, did you try compiling form the command line?

Comment: @user74973 -- the additional information you inserted isn't the result of `\listfiles`; it's the beginning of your log file.  the `\listfiles` output is at the *end* of the log file.  please replace what's there now with the real files information.

Comment: @barbara beeton   Where is the .log file?  The files that `MikTeX` makes are `.Text`, .`AUX`, and `SYNCTEX`.

Comment: @Bernard  See my comment to Barbara Beeton.

Comment: @user74973 -- sorry, i'm not a miktex user (work on a linux system), so i can't tell you where to look.  i'd find it surprising that no log file is created, but perhaps miktex "cleans up", and deletes presumed "unnecessary" files so they don't clutter your workspace.  a more experienced miktex user should know.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Obviously the "`.Text`" file mentioned by the OP is the log-file (as one can see from the content). Perhaps windows hides the extension but shows the file type.

Comment: There is not much point adding a bonus to this. It would be better by far to add the information requested to the question. Right now, it is not answerable. Nobody can reproduce the problem (so far). The output from `\listfiles` would help a great deal as we are not mind readers. 50 points does not, unfortunately, seem to be enough for a decent crystal ball. I guess it is inflation or something, but even Pound Predictors doesn't have one that cheap.

Comment: @cfr  I did add the  output from `\listfiles` to my post.  (I added the first dozen lines from it.)  I got the same  output that you got.

Comment: Please read [barbara's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278597/pdf-file-not-printed?noredirect=1#comment671210_278597). You have not given us the `\listfiles` output. That's just the regular start of the log. We are looking for the list of files with their versions produced by `\listfiles` so we can see if anything is out of date or otherwise non-standard.

Comment: @cfr  I copied everything from the `.Text` file.

Comment: @Bernard  I edited my post.

Comment: @user74973 open the `.log` file and look for the part where it lists the package names together with their version numbers and dates. It is in the same folder with your `.tex` file. What you add is not what they are asking for.

Comment: @user74973 -- is that really *everything* from your `.Text` file? it should be a *lot* longer.  if the job produced any pages, even if they weren't printed, they should be indicated in the log (`.Text`) file as `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.  as it is, it looks like the job never even finished reading in packages.  instead, the file ends with the input of the next-to-last tikz package, `patterns`.  there is no indication that the `pgfplots` package was read.  (i have used parenthesis-matching in a copy of the file in emacs to check this.)

Comment: @user74973 -- if this really is the end of your log (`.Text`) file, then perhaps the job went into a loop somewhere.  but we don't have enough information to say where.  it's vaguely possible that the `pgfplots` package on your system is corrupt, and.  if that's the case. perhaps someone else can suggest how to test that independently.

Comment: @barbarabeeton How does parentheses-matching help establish whether a package was read? (I ask because this sounds useful but I'm not sure how it works.) Do you think if the OP downloaded a copy of `pgfplots` from CTAN and put the files in the working directory, that would help establish whether the problem is with the installed version? I realise that the version might be different, so it might create problems to use the downloaded version in the document, but just as a crude test for a problem with the installed version. Even if the version is wrong, we shouldn't get a loop on reading.

Comment: Or use MikTeX's package manager to force a reinstallation of `pgfplots`, maybe?

Comment: @cfr -- the last option requested for `tikz` is `patterns`.  at the end of the posted log is `File: pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex 2008/03/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.13)
))` and that last paren matches the opening paren for reading in the `patterns` code.  when i typed in another paren at the end, it matched the line at the top of the file: `(Compile-2.tex`.  so i knew that it was a "clean" transition.  next thing in the input is `\usepackage{pgfplots}` and there's no sign of that.  q.e.d.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. That was my guess. (I used Kile's parentheses matching, but I assume it is the same principle.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Does TeX print the filename as soon as it finds it or does it start reading it first? If the former, it is hard to see how it could be a corrupt pgfplots. (Either it would not find it or it would find it and print the location to the log. Even if it couldn't read it.)

Comment: @cfr -- maybe downloading a new copy of `pgfplots` into the connected directory would help, but i think a test trying to read in *just* the existing version, and doing nothing else but trying to output "hello world" might show whether there is a flaw in the existing local package.  (pretty low cost test, so not much lost if it doesn't prove anything.)

Comment: @cfr -- in order to report the version, actually needs to read it.  (we should move this to chat, i guess, if there's much more to say.)

Comment: @cfr  I am using a new computer.  It is possible that an error occurred in downloading MikTeX.  I will ask a technician at the shop from which I bought it about this.

Comment: Anyway, what is the end of the .log file? It would let us know if there *is* any pdf file to print.

Comment: @Bernard See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278597/pdf-file-not-printed?noredirect=1#comment672140_278597. It appears that's all there is.

Comment: Your system is obviously not up-to-date as the latex format is from 1.1.. But as the log-file stops when trying to read pgfplots.sty, I suspect that your main problem is that the package is not installed and that the on-the-fly installation fails. Install the package with the package manager

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using a configuration of your windows explorer that you should not.  As I can see from your comments your windows explorer looks like this (I named your MWE `278597.tex` after the running number in tex.stackexchange):

[image]

See the missing `.log` file end in the empty red circle and the missing checked checkbox in the menu for `Dateinamenerweiterungen` (right red circle).

Here you can't see the correct file endings like `.tex`, `.log` (very relevant for your question here!) etc. A file ending `.text` is not used by LaTeX ...

To change this follow please the red markings in the following screenshot (sorry, I have only an german windows, but I'm sure you will find the correct menu points and buttons on your system):

[image]

First click on `Ansicht` (english I guess `view`?), then search the text `Dateinamenerweiterung` (english I guess `file ending`?) and click into the box.  Now you can see all file endings you need to work with windows.  Do not believe that Windows recommendition "Do not use file endings" is realy a good one ...

Now if we ask you to check the `.log` file or the `.aux` file for example you can always use the right file ;-)

The following screenshot shows the result of command `\listfiles` on my computer.

[image]

I marked the same versions I can identify in your posted `.log` file.

Because the list of used class and packages with version numbers is added at the **end** of the `.log` file and it seems that you did not see it on your computer it seems that your system can't compile to an end.  Where it stops you can see if you check the end of the `.log` file you get.

Now have a look to this screenshot:

[image]

There I marked where your `.log` file ends and how it continues on my system (red circle).  As you can see your file ends with two `))`.  That means that the last two opend files (marked at column 1 with a `(`) could complete their actions.  So it seems that your file `pgfplots.sty` has a problem (red arrow) to load.  The reason for that could be a faulty installation, a faulty file `pdfplots.sty` or another problem (perhaps with windows we can't  know with your given informations).

So I would ask you to

1. reboot your computer and try compilation once again.  No Error? Good. Same error?
2. check your windows. Do you have system errors? No? Good. Yes? Correct them.
3. reinstall MiKTeX (best would be to install the complete version). No Error? Good! Same error? Are you sure the installation was complete without errors and did you run after installing the MiKTeX package manager to update all installed packages?

Comment: Yes.  Here is what happened.  I bought a new personal computer (Microsoft, Windows 7) and had `WinEdt 9.1` installed.  I copied code written in `WinEdt 8.1` from my old computer into a file on my new computer.  The technician said that there is computer code "attached to" to my `LaTeX` code.  Apparently, the computer code was not compatible with `WinEdt 9.1`.  The technician said that I could either manually type the file again or he could install `WinEdt 8.1` on my new computer.  I had him do the latter, and the code in my post compiled correctly.

Comment: I had `WinEdt 8.1` on my old computer.  I don't know why code written on `WinEdt 8.1` from an older version of Windows would not be compatible with `WinEdt 9.1` on a newer version of Windows.  It wasted me a lot of time, though.  I appreciate your explanation.  Apparently, other users did, too.